# Can I make my Mac OS X Terminal color items according to syntax, like the Ubuntu terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal, switching

I want it to have all the colors for syntax folders, etc... How can I do that?

Comment: Also see [Colorizing your terminal and shell environment?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/148/colorizing-your-terminal-and-shell-environment) on [unix.stackexchange.com](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: (Link is broken to http://media.tannern.com/stackoverflow/Tanner%202.terminal)

Comment: Fixed 2 years later :)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

### My terminal colors

[image: terminal color examples]

### how to do it

#### download theme

from here: http://media.tannern.com/tanner.terminal

#### import into Terminal

After installing SIMBL and the correct terminalcolors you can import my terminal theme from the Terminal Preferences window.

[image: where to find the import option]

### other tweaks

Adding this to the file `~/.profile` will make `ls` color it's output by default.

```
# Make ls use colors
export CLICOLOR=1
alias ls='ls -Fa'
```

Adding this will define colors as variables to make a prompt easier to edit.

```
# define colors
C_DEFAULT="\[\033[m\]"
C_WHITE="\[\033[1m\]"
C_BLACK="\[\033[30m\]"
C_RED="\[\033[31m\]"
C_GREEN="\[\033[32m\]"
C_YELLOW="\[\033[33m\]"
C_BLUE="\[\033[34m\]"
C_PURPLE="\[\033[35m\]"
C_CYAN="\[\033[36m\]"
C_LIGHTGRAY="\[\033[37m\]"
C_DARKGRAY="\[\033[1;30m\]"
C_LIGHTRED="\[\033[1;31m\]"
C_LIGHTGREEN="\[\033[1;32m\]"
C_LIGHTYELLOW="\[\033[1;33m\]"
C_LIGHTBLUE="\[\033[1;34m\]"
C_LIGHTPURPLE="\[\033[1;35m\]"
C_LIGHTCYAN="\[\033[1;36m\]"
C_BG_BLACK="\[\033[40m\]"
C_BG_RED="\[\033[41m\]"
C_BG_GREEN="\[\033[42m\]"
C_BG_YELLOW="\[\033[43m\]"
C_BG_BLUE="\[\033[44m\]"
C_BG_PURPLE="\[\033[45m\]"
C_BG_CYAN="\[\033[46m\]"
C_BG_LIGHTGRAY="\[\033[47m\]"
```

Adding this will give you a multi-line colored prompt.

```
# set your prompt
export PS1="\n$C_LIGHTGREEN\u$C_DARKGRAY@$C_BLUE\h $C_DARKGRAY: $C_LIGHTYELLOW\w\n$C_DARKGRAY\$$C_DEFAULT "
```

For a list of escape sequences to use in prompts check this [article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-tip-prompt)

Comment: The link supplied in your answer is gone.

Comment: I've since stopped using Apple's Terminal application in favor of iTerm2 ( http://www.iterm2.com ) I prefer it's split windows over tabs and it does not need any hacks to support correct coloring (although I haven't used Apple's Terminal in some time and it may no longer need the hack listed above)

Comment: Can I use this theme for gnome shell? If yes how can I do? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @rennat The problem with posting links to blog posts is that they go away and are unreliable, please update this post with the instructions from your blog

Comment: @surfer190 I removed the link to that guys blog post since it's no longer necessary to patch terminal for proper color support.

Comment: +1 for the "other tweaks" section. The export and alias were exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 21):

geekology.co.za has an informative blog post on how to do this, ["Enabling Terminals directory and file color highlighting in Mac OS X"](http://www.geekology.co.za/blog/2009/04/enabling-bash-terminal-directory-file-color-highlighting-mac-os-x/). In case it gets moved or deleted, the basics are:

Add to your .bashrc or .profile:

```
export CLICOLOR=1
export LSCOLORS=ExFxCxDxBxegedabagacad
```

Save the file. Open a new terminal and use

```
ls
ls -l
ls -la
ls -lah
```

The rest of the article has info on what the colors do and how to change them (the letters you assign to LSCOLORS is what controls what colors you see).

Comment: +1 for not simply linking to the answer and including the core of it here.

Comment: Looks like the link is 404

Comment: Here's a tool to help customize the scheme: [https://geoff.greer.fm/lscolors/](https://geoff.greer.fm/lscolors/)

Answer (score 10):

As of Mac OS X Lion 10.7, Terminal allows you to customize the sixteen ANSI colors and also supports the 256-color palette.

So, installing SIMBL or other extensions to get more colors is no longer necessary.

Answer (score 1):

People may want to check out [zsh + prezto](https://github.com/sorin-ionescu/prezto). There's a nice guide [here](http://mikebuss.com/2014/02/02/a-beautiful-productive-terminal-experience). zsh is already installed in OSX. Prezto just adds stuff to your shell. Activate the syntax-highlighting module, and go to town :)

Comment: Looks like the link to the guide is broken. Giving a 404 :(

Comment: @Eric Thanks, I fixed the link.  Also see the follow-up article [here](http://mikebuss.com/2014/04/07/customizing-prezto)

Comment: just installed looks really nice and clean

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I use in 2023 to get Ubuntu colors for `ls` (which was my biggest pain when switching to Mac terminal). Looks like the Ubuntu color scheme has changed since the [post by @sorens above](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/9822/425650), as what that post suggests doesn't match what I have on Ubuntu at all.

Add this to your `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`:

```
# Use default ls output on Ubuntu
alias ls='ls -Fa'

# Use Ubuntu coloring scheme (as close as it gets)
export CLICOLOR=1
export LSCOLORS=ExGxFxbaCxbabahbaDacec
```

I believe it's as close as it gets to Ubuntu. I compiled this manually, based on the original `dircolors -b` output from my Ubuntu (`dircolors` is the util used to generate coloring of various file/dir types there).
I tested it for a while, but if you happen see any mismatches, please write a comment.

A couple of mismatches that I believe cannot be fixed on Mac:

1. A couple of colors are not an exact match (orange background -> yellow as Mac's `ls` doesn't have orange, orange foreground -> red) but it looks almost the same on my computer.
2. Unfortunately Mac's `ls` doesn't allow coloring of file types, so images, video, audio files and archives aren't colored as in Ubuntu. I see no way to distinguish those files in Mac `ls`. Which is a huge miss indeed.

### References

This may be useful if you want to tweak the colors.

1. My original dircolors -b output (I trimmed the big part with file extension coloring, as I don't believe it can be used on Mac). So that you can compare the differences if necessary and start from there. Not everything below has its match in `LSCOLORS` variable used on Mac, the latter is much simpler.

   `LS_COLORS='rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:';`
2. Explanation of dircolors syntax: https://linuxhint.com/ls_colors_bash/
3. A more detailed one: http://www.bigsoft.co.uk/blog/2008/04/11/configuring-ls_colors